# Insert to multiple tables in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP. Now I'm struggeling with a problem I can't find an answer for on the internet for the past hour. I'm trying to save the following array to my database:

```
array(
    'Product' => array(
        'product_id' => '77adfe7754esda71r1999431',
        'supplier_id' => 'zalando_it',
        'product_name' => 'Sweater',
        'price_new' => '68.97',
        'affiliate_url' => 'http://example.com'
    ),
    'Image' => array(
        'image' => '99988_DP.jpg'
    )
)
```

Now this is an example of my ERD: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zvfqfxes53gibb/example.png

I connected the tables correctly in the Models (by using belongsTo and hasMany variables), but still I think I'm doing something wrong.... Cause when I use the function **$this->Supplier->saveAssociated($data)** in the Model "Feed" it doesn't save anything.
And when I use **$this->Supplier->Product->saveAssociated($data)** it saves the Product and it creates records in the Image table with the product_id but leaves the "image" field empty.

Only if I use **$this->Supplier->Product->Image->saveAssociated($data)** it saves everything correctly. But isn't that wrong? Cause to my opinion it doesn't seem right to  go through each model ($this->Supplier->Product->Image...) to save all tables.... Or am I wrong?

Comment: did you try  $this->Supplier->saveAssociated($data, array('deep' => true));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Product hasMany Image, your data needs to be like this (notice "Image" is numbered, so there can be more than one):

```
array(
    'Product' => array(
        'product_id' => '77adfe7754esda71r1999431',
        'supplier_id' => 'zalando_it',
        'product_name' => 'Sweater',
        'price_new' => '68.97',
        'affiliate_url' => 'http://example.com'
    ),
    'Image' => array(
        0 => array(
            'image' => '99988_DP.jpg'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. unfortunately I can't get it working with $this->Supplier->saveAll($data), but $this->Supplier->Product->saveAll($data) works. At least I don't have to call every Model in the function, anymore :)

Comment: Right - it won't save if you just run a save on Supplier, because there is no supplier data to save.  Glad it helped!